# Efficiently handle malicious connection attempts to server? (Logged as "Connection closed by xx port xx [preauth]" in /var/log/auth.log)?

Tags: ssh, security, logs, sshd, authentication

I wanted to know what efficient way is there to handle malicious attempts to connect to my server. As mentioned, the attempts show up logged in `/var/log/auth.log` as `Connection closed by IPaddress port XXX [preauth]`.

### Additional info about `sshd_config`:

- Password login is disabled
- `MaxAuthTries 3`
- `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
- `PasswordAuthentication no`
- `PermitEmptyPasswords no`
- `DenyUsers pi admin ubuntu`

### The question's first part is: *should I even bother to block these attempts?*

There is about one attempt every few seconds.
The attempts come from different IPs (I can handle the ones that try to login multiple times to no success *I think*), but the sheer amount of connection attempts seems to be a bit of a pain in the neck.

One condition would be that I don't want to whitelist only certain IPs for ssh connection to the server.

Now **if** I **should block** these attempts, I'd love to have some suggestions about how to handle that (*apart from fail2ban please*).

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that since your question is centered a lot around the security aspect, I would recommend posting it at [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and for the suggestion. I guess I'm going to do that indeed! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you've restricted things to only public key authentication, then you're probably fine.  (Note that that means you should also turn `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `no`.)  For extra security you can turn off `PermitRootLogin` as well.

I run a server which gets scans all the time and I don't worry about it because they don't have my key, I don't have password authentication turned on, and there's no practical possibility of them getting in.

You can use something like fail2ban if you want, but it's not required.  If you're okay with a little log noise, then just ignore it.  You can also manually add problem parties or obviously uninteresting networks (e.g., a telecom in a country you'd never travel to) to the firewall if they're a huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

VPN is the best suggestion. Place a VPN server ([OpenVPN](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) for example) between your SSH server and internet. This is fairly simple, whether your server is located at home or in the cloud. Your SSH server will only listen to private IP for SSH connections. Your VPN server will be exposed to the internet (1194/UDP or 943/TCP or 443/TCP). OpenVPN is so flexible that you can use certificates to authenticate (avoid passwords).

This means you must first connect to VPN before you hit the target SSH server. Also, SSH access to the VPN server must be accessible via private IP for security reasons. This means that you must first connect to VPN before you can SSH into your VPN server for management purpose. But there is a risk of locking yourself out if things go wrong.

Plan B is to whitelist users in the `sshd_config` file and make sure they authenticate using ssh keys ONLY. Make use of the parameter [AllowUsers or AllowGroups](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-security-cookbook/0596003919/ch03s14.html). Whoever does not belong to the holy list, will be denied SSH access.

Plan C is to enable [Two Factor Authentication (2FA)](https://www.a2hosting.co.za/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/enabling-two-factor-authentication-for-ssh). Whitelisted users will be required to enter 2FA codes before granted access